# Converting smoothened values from Mandelbrot to an int[] array from the setRGB() method

Tags: mandelbrot

I have a list of double values that range from `0` to `1` as a result of my mandelbrot generator. These are resultant values from using a smooth algorithm to smooth out the values.

I am in the process of drawing them onto a `BufferedImage,` however, the `BufferedImage` calls for the `bi.setRGB()`, which for my example, looks like this: `bi.setRGB(0, 0, width, height, myPixel, 0, width);`

As you can tell, the `myPixel` is an `int[]` array.

This is my snippet within the Mandelbrot smoothing:

```
double nsmooth = iter + 1 - Math.log(Math.log(Math.abs(_Z.getMag()))/Math.log(2))/Math.log(2);
myPixel[ myY * width + myX ] = (nsmooth / maxIterations);
```

The second line above are values ranging from 0.0 to 1.0 (`nsmooth / maxIterations`), but since `myPixel[]` is an int array, I need some way to convert them to integer. Multiplying them by a factor of 10000+ did not work.

My question is, with my doubles from `0` to `1.0`, what is it that I can do to convert them to a compliable object that `setRGB` can accept?

Thank you.

Attempt 2:

`myPixel[ myY * width + myX ] = (int)(nsmooth / maxIterations * 500);`

It appears I was casting `nsmooth` only which resulted in `0` in every single value. I now casted the entire line, and multiplying it by a factor of 500. It looks a bit better, but maybe my value needs to be bigger:

[image]

Comment: Is your problem that you don't like the dynamic range you are getting -- the values between 0.0..1.0 do not appear in a linear form?

Comment: I seem to have fully solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
double nsmooth = iter + 1 - Math.log(Math.log(Math.abs(_Z.getMag()))/Math.log(2))/Math.log(2);

myPixel[ myY * width + myX ] = (int)(nsmooth / maxIterations * 500);
```

It appears the issue I had was that I casted `nsmooth` (a 0 to 1.0 decimal) to `int` which always resulted in 0.